# firetray in thunderbird not working properly

Tags: gnome, thunderbird

to day I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. After all updates were conducted I installed gnome-session-fall back (I am using gnome metacity).
In thunderbird 38.2.0 I installed Firetray 0.5.6.1 to see it in the notification applet in the panel of gnome.
However this functionality is not working properly. It shows up but I but selecting any of the options (i.e. show/hide) when clicking the icon has no effects. In the case of show/hide nothing happens the window stays.
When I click closing, the whole program closes down not minimizing to tray at all.
any suggestions on this topic? Bizarrely everything works like a charme on a different machine.
Could it be a graphic card bug?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in 0.5.6.1. Install older version of the addon 0.5.1 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/firetray/versions/
and unset the with_appindicator in the config editor